# Install lync server on standalone server?

Tags: windows-server-2012, lync, lync-2013

In an attempt save resources I'm attempting to install Lync server 2013 on a standalone server I have just installed. I've just installed Windows Server 2012 Standard on a machine and am now I've been reading through Lync installation guides and I want to find one that relates to installing Lync on a secondary server separate to my main server.

Can anyone link such a guide? I assume I will probably have to join the domain and then configure link ADUC to my current forest.

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: You will indeed have to join the server to the domain.  What part of the installation process are you confused about.  I can't imagine it being any different then any other Microsoft installation.

Comment: So join the domain and then proceed as normal?

Comment: I can't see how it would be any different if you were installing it on the master domain server itself.  I assume there is an Exchange server within your network?

Comment: @Ramhound it is a bit more complex. The OP has to move all roles onto the new server, update the topology, export/import the CMS, move the SQL Server etc etc... Not so trivial ! i am actually trying to write a more improved answer

Comment: @user2196728 - How many of those steps would you have to do if it were on the master domain server?  Moving the roles and the changing the topology seems sort of obvious.  Look forward to the answer if it actually isn't as simple as it appears to be.

Comment: `How many of those steps would you have to do if it were on the master domain server?` same steps, plus a little more in that case. I agree it can seems sort of obvious, but as far as the OP asks if he will have to probably join the domain, as it is the very first requirement, i don't know his knowledge about the whole thing, so don't seems to be so obvious for everyone. That is just what i wanted to say in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best and safest way to achieve this is to create a new pool for your new server.

Then, you will have to :

- Export/import and update topology
- create a new CMS
- import/export old CMS into the new one
- move all roles
- move users to the new pool
- Update DNS A and SRV records
- etc...(more in links provided below)
- And finally, of course, decommission the old Lync server

Of course your new standalone server has to be joined to the domain, as it is the very first requirement.
There are also other requirements before starting to install Lync 2013 on a server. They are described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398588.aspx) and within links provided on the page.

I've started writing a step by step, but as i am lazy (and mainly because i cannot test it in real time) i finally found someone with almost the same problem who wrote a guide :)
It is [here](http://cmcgreanor.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/move-lync-central-management-store-and-front-end-servers-to-a-new-lync-pool-with-a-new-sql-backend/) ! In his case it is about Lync 2010 but i cannot see anything that will not work in Lync 2013.

In fact, these steps are very similar to the ones required for a Lync 2010 to 2013 upgrade. So, i think that this [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205369.aspx) may help also (mainly links into this Technet).

Now i am afraid of [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) and his opinion ;) ;)

Hope it will help a bit.

Good luck, enjoy your new year's eve ! Best wishes !